# How do you populate an array with String input from a file?

Tags: java, arrays

Assume that i have 4 grades in testgrades.txt I don't know why this wont work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    File file1= new File("testgrades.txt");
    int cnt = 4;
int[] grades = new int[cnt];
String line1;
for (int i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
    Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(file1);
    line1 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    int grades2 = Integer.parseInt(line1);
    grades[i] = grades2;
}


    System.out.print(grades);
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript...

Comment: But you code is [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), not [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should note that arrays in java hold fixed-size elements of the same type.
You can initialize them in one of two ways (not very sure if there are other ways).

```
//First method
int[] anArray = new int[10];
// Second method
int[] anArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

In either case, the array is of size 10 elements. Since you are fetching the data from the text file, I'll suggest you count number of lines into a variable and use that value to initialize the array. Then you can use a loop to fill the values this way:

```
// Assuming you have cnt as your total count of grades.
int[] grades = new int[cnt];
String line1;
for (int 1=0; i<cnt; i++) {
    line1 = inputFile2.nextLine();
    int grades2 = Integer.parseInt(line1);
    grades[i] = grades2;
}
```

This is coming off my head so let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: it was working but I changed something and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "92.0,65.0,85.0,88.0"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Chapter8.AndrewMOntezreadfile.main(AndrewMOntezreadfile.java:35)

Comment: @AndrewMontez, I believe your problem now is with parsing the values from the text file. As you can tell from the error, the value read was `"92.0,65.0,85.0,88.0"` which the compiler cannot convert to int. That is why it is complaining.

I would suggest you read about CSV parsing from here: [CSV Parsing](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            // TODO code application logic here
            File file= new File("testgrades.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
            int arr[] = new int[100];
            int i = 0;
            do{
                String line1 = scan.nextLine();
                int grades2 = Integer.parseInt(line1);
                arr[i++] = grades2;
            }while(scan.hasNextLine());

            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                System.out.println(arr[j]);
            }
        }
```